# HTTP Live Stream stops playing after a while

Tags: linux, http, ffmpeg, stream, ffserver

I have a problem with streaming with ffserver. After I start ffserver and desktop-capture, everything seems to work fine.

Then I open the browser and access the output(http://localhost:8090/test1.mpeg). It
plays fine for 6-7 seconds then it stops and I have to refresh the page to get it work again. Does anyone know why that happens and how I can correct it?

Here is my ffserver.conf

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 40000
CustomLog -

<Feed feed1.ffm>
  File /tmp/feed1.ffm
  FileMaxSize 10000K
  ACL allow 127.0.0.1
  ACL allow localhost
  ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Feed>

<Stream test1.mpeg>
  Feed feed1.ffm
  Format mpeg
  AudioBitRate 32
  AudioChannels 1
  AudioSampleRate 44100
  VideoBitRate 300
  VideoFrameRate 30
  VideoSize 1280x1024
  VideoCodec mpeg1video
  AudioCodec libvorbis
  NoAudio
  StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```

my desktop-capture:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 40 -s 800x600 -framerate 50  -i :0.0+4,529 -map 0 -codec:v mpeg1video -codec:a libvorbis http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that the VideoBitRate was too low. I changed it to 3000 and now it runs without Problems.

now my ffserver.conf looks like this:

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 40000
CustomLog -

<Feed feed1.ffm>
   File /tmp/feed1.ffm
   FileMaxSize 10000K
   ACL allow 127.0.0.1
   ACL allow localhost
   ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Feed>

<Stream test1.mpeg>
   Feed feed1.ffm
   Format mpeg
   AudioBitRate 50
   AudioChannels 1
   AudioSampleRate 44100

   # Bitrate for the video stream
   VideoBitRate 3000

   VideoFrameRate 30
   VideoSize 1280x1024
   VideoCodec mpeg1video
   AudioCodec libvorbis
   NoAudio
   StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```